# The output of the command `i3 --help` is not grepable

Tags: bash, i3

When I type `i3 --help` I get this output :

```
Usage: i3 [-c configfile] [-d all] [-a] [-v] [-V] [-C]

-a          disable autostart ('exec' lines in config)
-c <file>   use the provided configfile instead
-C          validate configuration file and exit
-d all      enable debug output
-L <file>   path to the serialized layout during restarts
-v          display version and exit
-V          enable verbose mode

--force-xinerama
Use Xinerama instead of RandR.
This option should only be used if you are stuck with the
old nVidia closed source driver (older than 302.17), which does
not support RandR.

--get-socketpath
Retrieve the i3 IPC socket path from X11, print it, then exit.

--shmlog-size <limit>
Limits the size of the i3 SHM log to <limit> bytes. Setting this
to 0 disables SHM logging entirely.
The default is 0 bytes.

If you pass plain text arguments, i3 will interpret them as a command
to send to a currently running i3 (like i3-msg). This allows you to
use nice and logical commands, such as:

i3 border none
i3 floating toggle
i3 kill window
```

For any other command I have encountered until now, the output of such a `--help` option could always be piped and parsed by a second command like `grep` or `cat`, and that I verified working here.

Do you know why the output of `i3 --help` is not behaving that way ? I'm really a noob about file descriptors, but I have the feeling it's got something to do with them. However, I haven't got a clue where to go look at that point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably this command send output to STDERR. And you can grep it on this way:

```
i3 --help 2>&1|grep string
```

this `2>&1` will redirect the output of STDERR (file handler 2) to STDOUT (file handler 1)

Comment: Lol thanks a lot from a humble noob.

Comment: `i3 --help |& grep string`

Comment: @PotroNik can you explain what this does exactly ? (For reference, I only know `&` used to put a command in background, but not used along with a pipe.)

Comment: @Atralb `If ‘|&’ is used, command1’s standard error, in addition to its standard output, is connected to command2’s standard input through the pipe; it is shorthand for 2>&1 |. This
implicit redirection of the standard error to the standard output is performed after any
redirections specified by the command.` https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.pdf